# React Router Link ForceUpdate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hyperlink, router

i want to refresh whole page when user click home button. I am using

```
this<Link onClick={this.forceUpdate} to="/">HOME</Link>
```

It works as expected, but i have this error. Any idea why i am getting it ?

```
Cannot read property 'enqueueForceUpdate' of undefined
```

I am assuming that this is not defined, not sure why tho.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: try with window.refresh()  . . .

Comment: Probably you need to do write `onClick={() => this.forceUpdate()}` because forceUpdate here isn't called with the correct context

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this when someone clicks on Home :

```
onClick={()=>{window.location.href = '/';}}
```

This will navigate user to Home page and refresh the App.

Comment: I tried implementing your solution like this, but i am getting following error : Cannot set property 'location' of undefined

render() {return (
            <div className="navbar">
                <Link onClick={this.refreshPage} to="/">DOMU</Link>
            </div>
        )
    }  

   refreshPage = () => {
        window.href.location = '/';
    }

Comment: sorry it was `window.location.href`. I edited my answer